# How to use variables as arguments/parameters to subprocess module

Tags: python, variables, subprocess

For example

```
TestString= 'User'
subprocess.run([r"psshutdown.exe", "\\\\192.168.0.1 -u "+TestString])
```

The `TestString` is changed to his uppercase `USER`.
Why and how can I avoid it?

Comment: `subprocess.run` doesn't do that by itself. `psshutdown` must be doing it.

Comment: Normally psshutdown doesn't change the parameters!

Comment: Just verifying that `subprocess` doesn't change parameters: `t="User"; subprocess.run([r"echo", ""+t])` outputs `User`

Comment: Not it is subprocess to change variables directly! But if you don't write the arguments like barmar wrote it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put each command argument in a separate list element. The way you've done it, it thinks `"\\\\192.168.0.1 -u "+TestString` is a single parameter, the name of the computer to shut down. Computer names are case-insensitive, so it's converting it to uppercase.

```
subprocess.run([r"psshutdown.exe", r"\\192.168.0.1", "-u", TestString])
```

Comment: How i must write if i wanto to pass more arguments? For example
`subprocess.run([r"psshutdown.exe", r"\\", Value[0], "-u", Value[3], "-p", Value[4], "-f"])` doesn't work

Comment: What is `Value[0]`? If that's the IP, you need `r"\\" + Value[0]` to concatenate them, not put them in separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks, yes Value[0] is the ip! Can you explain why?

Comment: Each list element is a separate argument. `\\192.168.0.1` should be one argument, not two arguments.